# Laravel docker container not serving website

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image for kubernetes cluster using Dockerfile for a **Laravel** website. I have not much experience with docker, so I searched internet and found a Dockerfile with docker-compose where I can run the website. But I want to use only Dockerfile and keep the Website only in a single container, no database or other container and no docker-compose.yaml file. Can you suggest me what should I need to do to make a single docker container that only serves the website? I want to use nginx as the web server.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libzip-dev \
    nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd xml zip

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -d /home/hridoy hridoy
RUN mkdir -p /home/hridoy/.composer && \
    chown -R hridoy:hridoy /home/hridoy

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

ADD . .

RUN composer install --no-interaction

USER hridoy
```

I am using a custom nginx config file and here is the file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When I run docker build command, it builds the image successfully and I can also run the image using `docker run -p 8080:80 app`
But when I go to `localhost:8080`, I cannot access the website. The browser gives me the error-

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: if you log in to the running container `docker exec -it IMAGE_ID bash`, can you do  `curl localhost` or connect to it with `nc -zv 127.0.0.1 80`? Have you checked the logs within the container?

Comment: It's bad practice - nginx and php in one container. Make another dockerfile for nginx and connect it ti php with fpm port: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

Comment: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused` this is the response when I try `curl localhost` inside docker container. @RobEvans

Comment: seems the service hasn't started or hasn't started on the port expected. Check `ps -ef | grep SERVICE_NAME` and see whether its actually running